# Are there diagnostic helpers for MS.DI configuration testing?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm setting up some testing to automatically check that our DI has been configured correctly. In particular we want to ensure that the lifestyles of dependancies match (so we don't get transients injected into singletons) and to avoid using the service locator as much as possible, relying on the constructor injection instead.

In the past we've used Castle.Windsor as our service provider, which comes with diagnostic classes and functions to help catch these problems. Are there similar functions for MS.DI or is it something we'll have to roll ourselves?

Comment: If this is a feature you want (and I can imagine), why would you stick with MS.DI? Why not use Castle Windsor or Simple Injector? They are mature and contain these features. These are features that MS.DI will never have.

Comment: It's important to realize that `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` is mostly just a facade. It has a default (and basic) provider, but if you need more power, you can sub in an alternate provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with the advice from Steven & Chris, developers are not always in charge of the infrastructure they have to use. Where possible I will be pushing for Castle.Windsor, since it's what my team is most familiar with, but in this case we managed to cobble together the tests we wanted ourselves.

I'm presenting the test pattern here in case someone stumbles across this question and has the same struggles, but please do consider using a better DI provider, especially if you're still at the start of your project.

```
[Test]
public void Assert_Lifetimes_Are_Consistent()
{
    var missing = new List<string>();
    var errors = new HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>();

    foreach (var service in _serviceCollection.Where(s => IsInYourAssembly(s.ServiceType)))
    {
        var serviceLifetimeRanking = LifetimeRanking(service.Lifetime);

        foreach (var fieldInfo in ((System.Reflection.TypeInfo)service.ServiceType).DeclaredFields.Where(fi => fi.FieldType.IsAbstract && IsInYourAssembly(fi.FieldType)))
        {
            var dependencyLifetime = _serviceCollection.SingleOrDefault(fi => fi.ServiceType == fieldInfo.FieldType)?.Lifetime;

            if (dependencyLifetime==null)
                missing.Add($"No service found for {fieldInfo.FieldType.FullName} as a dependency for {service.ServiceType.FullName}");

            var dependencyLifetimeRanking = LifetimeRanking(dependencyLifetime);

            if (dependencyLifetimeRanking > serviceLifetimeRanking)
                errors.Add(
                    Tuple.Create(
                        $"{service.ServiceType.Name} ({service.Lifetime})",
                        $"{fieldInfo.FieldType.Name} ({dependencyLifetime})"
                    )
                );
        }
    }

    if (missing.Any()||errors.Any())
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendJoin(Environment.NewLine, missing);

        if (errors.Any())
        {
            sb.AppendLine("Following dependency pairs have inconsistent lifestyles:");
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors.Select(err => $"{err.Item1} -> {err.Item2}")));
        }

        Assert.Fail(sb.ToString());
    }
}

private bool IsInYourAssembly(Type type)
{
    return (type.Assembly.FullName?.IndexOf("YOUR_PROJECT_ASSEMBLY_HERE") ?? -1) == 0;
}
private int LifetimeRanking(ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime)
{
    switch (serviceLifetime)
    {
        case ServiceLifetime.Singleton:
            return 1;
        case ServiceLifetime.Scoped:
            return 2;
        case ServiceLifetime.Transient:
            return 3;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("serviceLifetime", serviceLifetime,
                $"Value is not a known member of the ServiceLifetime enum");
    }
}
```

If the test fails, it will return a list of missing dependancies followed by a list of incompatible dependancy lifetimes.

The `_serviceCollection` field needs to be populated and `Startup(config, env).ConfigureServices(_serviceCollection);` needs to be called before running the test.

The IsInYourAssembly is an important function to filter out all the generic types which are also returned in the `_serviceCollection`.